# Does the same code written in two different programming languages has same binary output?

Tags: compiler-construction, compilation, compiler-optimization

If i want to print "HELLO" in two different languages say c++ and java, does the binary output of the code may also be different.. ??

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the binary output of the code is different.

Also when using the same language with different compiler options the generated output may be different (with/without debugging information, with/without optimization).

Taking your example:

- In C++ the compiler generates machine code for direct execution of the CPU
- In java the compiler generates byte code which will be run through a byte code interpreter or jit (just in time compiler)

But in equivalent programs, the program output shall be the same (in your case `HELLO`).

Answer (score 0):

It depends on so many factors (source language, targeted platform, hardware, compiler flags, execution environment, ...).

A programming language specification usually describes language constructs and semantics without delving into implementation details leaving it to compiler vendors.

Some languages have very different dialect (e.g. C# and Visual Basic) but are compiled to same [managed code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Managed_code).

A program written in some language can be compiled to completely different binaries depending on targeted platform.

To provide maximum flexibility [compilers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler) are designed with modularity in mind and are composed of different parts (lexer, parser, IL optimizer, code generator) and compilation stages. This is why it is possible for example to extend GCC to support future platforms be attaching new code generators without touching other parts.